# Почему возникает Runtime error?

Tags: java

Привет. Пишу олимпиаду. Проверочная компиляция проходит на сервере. Хоть у меня у самого успешно компиляция проходит, на сервере происходит Runtime error. Не могли бы вы подсказать, из-за чего может возникать такая ошибка?

Задача сама по себе элементарная (Умножение матриц)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;


class solver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int Arows, Acols;
        int Brows, Bcols;

        try {
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // Get A array size
            String str1 = br1.readLine();
            String[] sub1 = str1.split(" ");
            Arows = Integer.parseInt(sub1[0]);
            Acols = Integer.parseInt(sub1[1]); 

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        } 

        int[][] Aarray = new int[Arows][Acols]; // Initialize and fill A array

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < Arows; i++) {
                BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String str2 = br2.readLine();
                String[] sub2 = str2.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < Acols; j++) {
                    Aarray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sub2[j]);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        } 

        try {
            BufferedReader br3 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // Get B array size
            String str3 = br3.readLine();
            String[] sub3 = str3.split(" ");
            Brows = Integer.parseInt(sub3[0]);
            Bcols = Integer.parseInt(sub3[1]); 
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        } 



        int[][] Barray = new int[Brows][Bcols]; // Initialize and fill A array

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < Brows; i++) {
                BufferedReader br4 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                String str4 = br4.readLine();
                String[] sub4 = str4.split(" ");
                for (int j = 0; j < Bcols; j++) {
                    Barray[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(sub4[j]);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return;
        } 

        if (Acols == Brows) {
            int iter;
            double res;
            double[][] Rarray = new double[Arows][Bcols]; // Initialize result array

            for (int i = 0; i < Arows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Bcols; j++) {
                    iter = 0;
                    res = 0;
                    while (iter < Acols) {
                        res = res + Aarray[i][iter]*Barray[iter][j];
                        iter = iter + 1;
                    }
                    Rarray[i][j] = res;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%d %d\n", Arows, Bcols);
            for (int i = 0; i < Arows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Bcols; j++) {
                    System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.0f ", Rarray[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.printf(Locale.US, "\n");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А сообщение об ошибке и stack trace вы предлагаете нам угадать?

Comment: Говорю же, сервер выдает ошибку, но саму ошибку не называет.
Но, собственно ideone.com указал на ошибку: NullPointerException

Comment: Видимо это проблемы самого сервера, я кажется знаю, что за сайт.
На этом сайте придётся другие языки использовать, сам всё перепробовал с явой вообще никак не хочет ужиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну все правильно. Чтобы прога работала, ей на вход (на stdin) должна подаваться строка. А строки нет, соответственно `readLine()` возвращает `null` - оттуда и ошибка. Надо ее переписать, чтобы прога ожидала (именно ожидала) подачи ей на вход данных.